# Creating new set of nHair System

Tags: python, maya

What is the python way to code out a new set of hair system? 
Apparently when I tried running my code, it can only creates the first set of hairSystem and when tried to re-run it again, it is unable to do so.

EDIT: I have managed to resolve my other issues but currently I am having issues with hairSystem

```
def createPlane(self):
        global nurbsPlane
        # Create the nurbsPlane
        nurbsPlane = cmds.nurbsPlane(n = "nurbsPlane", p=[0,0,0], ax = [0,1,0], w=1, lr=5, d=3, u=1,v=5, ch=1)
        cmds.select(nurbsPlane, r=True)
        # Cleanup the control vertexs
        mm.eval("createHair 1 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 2 1 1;")
        cmds.rename("hairSystem1Follicles", "hairSys_Follicles")
```

Comment: Your question includes too much code. [Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In the meantime, I'll give you this piece of advice: **don't use global variables** (exactly to avoid problems such as yours).

Answer (score 1):

Maya will throw an error while attempting to rename hairSystem1Follicles after the first run, as the object created would have a different name. This is one of the fundamental problems of the maya.cmds/MEL world. But to our advantage, createHair method keeps the hairSystem selected, after running successfully. We can leverage this fact to find out dynamically, the created hairSystemFollicles Group that you are trying to rename in your code. Here is a solution you can try:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pm

def createPlane(self):
    # Create the nurbsPlane
    nurbsPlane = cmds.nurbsPlane(n = "nurbsPlane", p=[0,0,0], ax = [0,1,0], w=1, lr=5, d=3, u=1,v=5, ch=1)
    cmds.select(nurbsPlane, r=True)
    # Cleanup the control vertices

    pm.language.Mel.eval("createHair 1 5 5 0 0 0 0 5 0 2 1 1;") # Pymel's evals are easier to debug and more robust
    created_hairsystem = pm.PyNode("hairSystem1")
    follicles_created = created_hairsystem.getShape().listFuture(type="follicle")
    follicles_group = pm.nodetypes.DagNode(follicles_created[0]).getParent(generations=2)
    cmds.rename(follicles_group, "hairSys_Follicles")
```

This method will always work.

Comment: Mine worked when changing the last line to:
cm.rename(follicles_group.name(), "hairSys_Follicles")